# GDB debug fails with "Unknown Signal" midway through execution on Windows

Tags: c++

I'm not so sure how to isolate this issue since I think it has to do with the memory. Basically, I'm trying to parse an input file to create a grid that tracks area the covered by an object as it moves through a grid. I'm using `vector<vector<int>>` to represent the grid, and I expand it as the item moves around. By the time the program stops, I have a 28 by 162 grid; hence, my guess that it has to do with memory.

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// NOTE: this would have been more efficient with std::deque

void extendGrid(vector<vector<int>>* gridptr, int headpos[], int tailpos[]) {
  int colSize = gridptr->size();
  int rowSize = gridptr->at(0).size();

  // head exceeds top limit
  if (headpos[0] < 0) {
    // add row to beginning of grid
    gridptr->insert(gridptr->begin(), vector<int>(rowSize));
    // shift headpos down
    headpos[0]++;
    // shift tailpos down
    tailpos[0]++;
  }

  // head exceeds bottom limit
  if (headpos[0] >= colSize) {
    gridptr->push_back(vector<int>(rowSize));
  }

  // head exceeds left limit
  if (headpos[1] < 0) {
    // add item to beginning of every row (add column)
    for (int i = 0; i < colSize; i++) {
      gridptr->at(0).insert(gridptr->at(0).begin(), 0);
    }
    // shift headpos right
    headpos[1]++;
    // shift tailpos right
    tailpos[1]++;
  }

  // head exceeds right limit
  if (headpos[1] >= rowSize) {
    // add column
    for (int i = 0; i < colSize; i++) {  // iterate over rows
      gridptr->at(i).push_back(0);       // add one element
    }
  }
}

// we assume headpos & tailpos have size 2
// ARRAYS DECAY INTO POINTERS --> PASS BY REFERENCE
void updateTail(int headpos[], int tailpos[]) {
  int diffX = headpos[0] - tailpos[0];
  int diffY = headpos[1] - tailpos[1];

  // check for diff of 2 in rows.
  // if tail moves in row direction, add column movement to it
  int tailXmovement = diffX / 2;
  tailpos[0] += tailXmovement;
  if (tailXmovement != 0) {
    tailpos[1] += diffY;
  }

  // same as previous, but reversed
  int tailYmovement = diffY / 2;
  tailpos[1] += tailYmovement;
  if (tailYmovement != 0) {
    tailpos[0] += diffX;
  }
}

int main() {
  // initialize grid with 1 because tail starts here
  vector<vector<int>> grid = {{1}};
  // initialize coords
  int headpos[2] = {0, 0};
  int tailpos[2] = {0, 0};

  int linecounter = 0;  // DEBUG

  // ifstream fs("./adventofcode.com_2022_day_9_input.txt");
  ifstream fs("./test_input.txt");
  char direction;
  int distance;
  while (fs >> direction >> distance) {
    linecounter++;                           // DEBUG
    cout << "line " << linecounter << endl;  // DEBUG
    cout << direction << distance << endl;   // DEBUG

    if (linecounter == 386) {  
      // line from input where problem occurs
      // sometimes it's sooner, sometimes later.
      cout << "aha!" << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {  // change one unit at a time
      // update head position
      if (direction == 'U') {
        headpos[0]--;  // one cell up
      } else if (direction == 'D') {
        headpos[0]++;  // one cell down
      } else if (direction == 'L') {
        headpos[1]--;  // one cell left
      } else if (direction == 'R') {
        headpos[1]++;  // one cell right
      } else {
        throw runtime_error("Invalid direction!");
      }

      // extend grid if necessary
      extendGrid(&grid, headpos, tailpos);

      // update tail position
      updateTail(headpos, tailpos);

      // set tail position value to 1
      grid[tailpos[0]][tailpos[1]] = 1;
    }
  }

  // count 1s in grid
  int tailcount = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].size(); j++) {
      if (grid[i][j] == 1) {
        tailcount++;
      }
    }
  }

  // answer
  cout << tailcount << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you using pointers with vectors that's unusual `vector<vector<int>>* `, and why are you mixing std::vector and "C" style arrays.  Do you know about passing by reference? So before you continue debugging (I assume you tried that) try to get at least rid of the legacy "C" constructs. "C" style arrays are too easy to use wrong (out-of-bound).

Comment: Is someone telling you to use "C" style arrays? // ARRAYS DECAY INTO POINTERS --> PASS BY REFERENCE. All in all I think you should make a grid class an put your operations on it in the class, much easier to keep track of invariants and boundaries that way. Also have a look at std::span.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Nice suggestion! Turns out it was just a logic error, but std::array did help me make the code more readable. I will never again use c-style arrays. Not worth the hassle.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, have you also changed `extendGrid(vector<vector<int>>* gridptr` to `extendGrid(vector<vector<int>>& grid`? One of the things is dat in current C++ (raw) pointers should be used sparingly.